# A rotating polygonal line with increasing side length cannot end up where it started!

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, summation-by-parts

Consider a polygonal line $P_0P_1\ldots P_n$ such that $\angle P_0P_1P_2=\angle P_1P_2P_3=\cdots=\angle P_{n-2}P_{n-1}P_{n}$, all measured clockwise. If $P_0P_1>P_1P_2>\cdots>P_{n-1}P_{n}$, $P_0$ and $P_n$ cannot coincide.

While the result is remarkable in itself, the following proof that appears in Titu's 'Mathematical Olympiad Challenges' is just mind blowing :

Let us consider complex coordinates with origin at $P_0$ and let the line $P_0P_1$ be the x-axis. Let $\alpha$ be the angle between any two consecutive segments and let $a_1>a_2>\cdots>a_n$ be the lengths of the segments. If we set $z=e^{i(\pi-\alpha)}$, then the coordinate of $P_n$ is $a_1+a_2z+\cdots+a_n z^{n-1}$. We must prove that this number is not equal to zero.

Using the Abel Summation lemma, we obtain,
$$a_1+a_2z+\cdots+a_{n-1}z^n=(a_1-a_2) + (a_2-a_3)(1+z) + \cdots + a_n(1+z+\cdots+z^{n-1})$$

If $\alpha$ is zero, then this quantity is a strictly positive real number, and we are done.

If not, multiply by $(1-z)$ to get $(a_1-a_2)(1-z) + (a_2-a_3)(1-z^2) + \cdots + a_n(1-z^n)$. This expression cannot be zero. Indeed, since $\mid z\mid=1$, by the triangle inequality, we have,
$$\mid (a_1-a_2)z + (a_2-a_3)z^2 + \cdots + a_n z^n \mid < (a_1-a_2) + (a_2-a_3) + (a_3-a_4) + \cdots + a_n$$

The conclusion follows.

I was wondering if one can prove this synthetically, without using complex numbers. Any alternate proof or suggestion in the direction of an alternate proof is welcome.

Comment: This can be reduced  to  the case where $n $ is prime, though I am not sure  how  it  helps

Comment: A synthetic solution is given in Titu's 'Mathematical Olympiad Treasures', problem 2.45

Comment: @Sandeep Silwal. Yeah, found it. Thanks. You can copy the proof as an answer if you want the bounty. :-P

Comment: Just curious, what do you mean by a 'synthetic' solution? Like a direct solution from only plane geometry reasoning?

Comment: @vujazzman, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_geometry .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the polygon was to return to the origin, then $n\alpha=2\pi$, because the returning line must make an angle of $\alpha$ with the starting line.

Place each edge of the polygon at the origin at an angle of $k\alpha$, starting on the positive $x$-axis, and working clockwise. Each line segment below the $x$-axis has a counterpart line segment above the $x$-axis, and the $y$-value is strictly larger, therefore the polygon cannot return to the origin.